# How to use Accumulate in Drools Excel rules table

Tags: drools

I need to track state change of an object and fire rules based on output of previous rule output, the examples I got from google results all use, accumulate function to track state. These were in DRLs but I want to do the same with Excel rules table,  can anyone provide example or links?

Comment: Decision tables (Excel) are rather inadequate for the kind of rules (using accumulate) you apparently need. -- Note that you can use decision table rules in combination with DRL rules.

Comment: @Laune, thanks a lot, could you please share if you have any links or references to how to use both decision table rules and DRL rules together for something like accumulate, thanks again